# QuerieConfig not getting identified by AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-textract

**I am running this code:**

```
 response = textract.start_document_analysis( DocumentLocation={  
 'S3Object': { 'Bucket': bucketname, 'Name': filename } }, FeatureTypes= ['QUERIES'], QueriesConfig={'Queries':[ {'Text':'{}'.format("Who are  
 you?")} ]}, NotificationChannel={ 'SNSTopicArn': SNS_TOPIC_ARN, 'RoleArn':   SNS_ROLE_ARN }, OutputConfig={ 'S3Bucket': OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME } )
```

**This is the error I am getting**:

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "QueriesConfig", must be one of: DocumentLocation, FeatureTypes, ClientRequestToken, JobTag, NotificationChannel, OutputConfig, KMSKeyId
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

**If I run it without QueriesConfig and give 'QUERIES' as FeatureTypes, I am getting the  error as below:**

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the StartDocumentAnalysis operation: QueriesConfig must be used with QUERIES FeatureType.",
"errorType": "InvalidParameterException"
```

**How do I resolve this?**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding a layer using the latest version of boto3.

Answer (score -1):

**Install the latest version of boto3 in your lambda temp workspace.**

```
import sys
from pip._internal import main

main(['install', '-I', '-q', 'boto3', '--target', '/tmp/', '--no-cache-dir', '--disable-pip-version-check'])
sys.path.insert(0,'/tmp/')

import boto3
```